# Image/ViewPager will not correctly use android:layout_gravity="bottom" and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Tags: java, xml, android-layout, android

For some reason  android:layout_gravity="bottom" and       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" on my ViewPager (the classical button) do not seem to place the image at the bottom of the screen and I'm unsure why.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

### SCREENSHOT:

[image]

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.idg.omv.ui.widget.VideosListView
        android:id="@+id/videosListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/groupScrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        </ScrollView>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/scroll_lt_arrow" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/fav_up_btn1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/scroll_rt_arrow" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried any other [`scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) values? It looks like `fitXY` is causing your problem here. I think you're either looking for `center` or `centerCrop`.

Comment: It is already centered... why would that move it to the bottom of the layout?

Comment: I simply need to move the "classical" /  ViewPager to the bottom instead of the middle of the screen

Comment: Ah, I see. I've been trying to fix this and I just went and read the Nav Drawer docs; you cannot do this quite like this. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Navigation Drawer documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) states (emphasis mine):

> To add a navigation drawer, declare your user interface with a `DrawerLayout` object as the root view of your layout. Inside the `DrawerLayout`, **add one view that contains the main content for the screen** (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer.

You cannot have multiple views in your DrawerLayout xml (other than your drawer and content). I would recommend putting your content in a fragment, and then inflating it in code similar to the way the examples do.